# Is there a way to either run all or no instructions inside a try block?

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch, try-except

I want to run a few instructions only if none of them throws an exception and skip all of them if at least one throws an exception.

I thought that was what a try-except would do but found out that the instructions inside of a try block are run until one instruction throws an exception, then the remaining instructions are skipped.

Some example code:

```
try:
    print("I'm printing " + "1")
    print("I'm printing " + "2")
    print("I'm printing " + "3")
    print("I'm printing " + "4")

except TypeError:
    print("STOP there was an exception!")
```

The output of the example code will be as following:

```
I'm printing 1
I'm printing 2
STOP there was an exception!
```

as mentioned before the instructions inside the try block are run until an exception is thrown.
Whereas I wanted to achieve that either none or all instructions inside the try block are run. So the output would be:

```
STOP there was an exception!
```

How is such behavior implemented if possible?

EDIT:

I found a *hacky* way which works at least if KeyErrors should be avoided.
I used the try block to assign each value to itself, used except to skip an iteration if an exception was thrown and simply put the instructions of which either all or none should have been run after the except.

Code looked like this in the end:

```
try:
    value1 = value1
    value2 = value2
    value3 = value3

except KeyError:
    continue

func1(value1)
func1(value2)
func1(value3)
```

func1 will now only be applied on all values if none of them would throw a KeyError. I know that's probably quite a special case but that was my solution, in case someone has a similar problem.

Comment: How can you possibly stop func1 from running dependant on what func2 which runs after it does? Its essentially the equivalent of me asking you to make sure you don't flip a coin on heads if I flip a tails after you

Comment: I see the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, this is not logically possible.  However, there *is* a field of effort in critical sections and "commits" -- how can you "stage" a set of changes to your virtual world, and not commit those changes until you reach some level of acceptability?

The difficulty of implementation depends on the side effects within your `try` block.  For instance, the version you posted is trivial: accumulate the desired output in a single string variable, which you emit only *after* the block is entirely successful.  The side effect is the appearance of output in a medium which the program no longer controls.

Your program is a model of something.  To make this conditional execution work, you need to create a virtual representation of your model.  You operate on that representation until you reach a point of certainty, at which to foist your virtual changes on the main model.  For instance, if you're working with a data base (a common paradigm for this problem), you either make a local copy and work on that, or you maintain a list of inverse operations to execute in case the sequence of changes fails (a complex "undo").

I hope these are enough leads to give you a concept of what you face, and how to find the appropriate direction for a total solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't break in between `print`s and tell I don't what to print the lines that are instructed to do so before. What printed are already printed.

One *hacky* way is to hold your instructions into a container and wrap it with a `try` - `except`:

```
instructions = []
try:
    instructions = ["I'm printing " + "1", "I'm printing " + "2", "I'm printing " + 3, "I'm printing " + "4"]
except TypeError:
    print("STOP there was an exception!")

print('\n'.join(instructions))
```

... which prints `"STOP there was an exception!"` if there is any `TypeError` else the instructions.

Comment: Thats great for strings, but what happens when an instruction includes calling an api or db?

Comment: @Sayse, it won't.